# Access ASP.Net Data Cache from a Web API method in same ASP.Net project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, data-caching

I need to remove ASP.Net cache from inside a Web API method. This cache by the name of 'ContentNames' was set in  the code-behind of an aspx page using following code. **Is this possible, and if yes, then how would I access ASP.Net data cache from inside the Web API method?**

The Web API and all the aspx pages are part of the same website project in Visual Studio 2013.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("ContentNames", dt, null,
      System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0));
```

The Web API method from where I need to access and remove 'ContentNames' data cache, looks like below.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage ApproveOrRejectContent( RadEditorContentAdminParas paras)
    {

         var data =  GetUnApprovedContent(paras.ApprovedOrRejected, paras.PageId);

          //NEED to remove a Cache by the name of 'ContentNames' ???

        return Request.CreateResponse<ContentsInfoResult>(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("ContentNames"); ?

Comment: In Web API? I think you cannot access it...not sure

Comment: Why not? add System.Web refernce and access

Comment: @OlegYudovich, You are correct. So simple, how did I miss it. Can you please write this as an answer. I used  following code with success. System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("ContentNames");

Comment: I guess Web API is integrated with ASP.Net in  4.5 version of .Net, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add reference of System.Web to your Web Api controller and you be able to access Current cache and remove it:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("ContentNames");
```